# bad operand types for binary operator '+'

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

I am working on creating a generic class to manipulate Matrices. But here is the problem: When I implement the addition operation, I get a "bad operand types for binary operator '+'"

It says that:

first type:  Object
  second type: T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Matrix

Is there a way to make it do the addition?

here is my code:

```
public class Matrix<T> {
    private T tab[][];
    public Matrix( T tab[][])
    {
       this.tab = (T[][])new Object[tab.length][tab[0].length];
       for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
            System.arraycopy(tab[i], 0, this.tab[i], 0, tab.length);
        }
    }

    public Matrix(int row, int column)
    {
       this.tab = (T[][])new Object[row][column];
    }

    //other constructors...

    public Matrix addition(Matrix otherMatrix)
    {
        Matrix tmp = new Matrix(otherMatrix.getRowLen(), otherMatrix.getColLen());
        for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < tab[0].length; j++){
                //the line with the error is below
               tmp.setElement(i, j, otherMatrix.getElement(i, j) + tab[i][j]);
            }
        }

        return tmp;
    }

    public int getRowLen(){
        return tab.length;
    }

    public int getColLen(){
        return tab[0].length;
    }

    public void setElement(int i, int j, T value){
        tab[i][j] = value;
    }

    public void setElement( T tab[][])
    {
       this.tab = (T[][])new Object[tab.length][tab[0].length];
       for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
            System.arraycopy(tab[i], 0, this.tab[i], 0, tab.length);
        }
    }

    public T getElement(int i, int j){
        return tab[i][j];
    }
}
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: Can't do operator overloading in java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Generic methods and numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850970/java-generic-methods-and-numbers). See also: [Java generics and the Number class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923081/java-generics-and-the-number-class)

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support using the `+` operator for anything but primitive numeric types and `Strings`.  Here, you can't use the `+` operator between any arbitrary objects.

You got an `Object` for the left hand side because `otherMatrix` is a raw (untyped) `Matrix`.  You got a `T` for the right hand side because `tab` is defined generically with `T`.

You cannot overload operators in Java, so you cannot have `+` defined for any `T`.

You may be able to get what you want by removing generics and using

```
private int tab[][];
```

or

```
private double tab[][];
```

depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that math operators are not suited for generic types (even when bounded by `Number`, see the [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850970/java-generic-methods-and-numbers)), you can easily pass a strategy for math operations when creating the matrix.

```
 public class Matrix<T> {

    private final MathOperations<T> operations;

    public Matrix(T[][] data, MathOperations<T> operations) {
       //...
       this.operations = operations;
    }

        //...
        tmp.setElement(i, j, operations.add(otherMatrix.getElement(i, j), tab[i][j]));
 }

 public interface MathOperations<T> {
     public T add(T operand1, T operand2);
     //... any other methods you need defined
 }

 public class IntegerMathOperations implements MathOperations<Integer> {
     public Integer add(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
         //(assuming non-null operands)
         return i1 + i2;
     }
 }
```