# Mathematical Operations on type generic methods

Tags: java, generics

How is it possible to perform mathematical operations on type generic functions?

If for example I have an interface of `Function` that takes two type arguments used for defining an inner method for producing its functionality. One argument is used for the return type and the other for the function's argument type.

Ex. : 
`Function<Integer, Integer> f = new specificFunction();`

How can the `specificFunction()` implementation perform any mathematical operations that depends on different types? i.e `Integer`, `float` etc..

Comment: Related: [Java: Generic methods and numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850970/java-generic-methods-and-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, you cannot. Generics are object-only. You cannot perform math on objects. It looks like you can because you can do something like this:

```
Integer a = 1;
Integer b = 2;
Integer c = a + b;
```

But that is only due to autoboxing. What actually happens is the compiler replaces that code with this:

```
Integer a = new Integer(1);
Integer b = new Integer(3);
Integer c = Integer.valueOf(a.intValue() + b.intValue());
```

And the type must be known to do that. The best you can do is something like this:

```
interface Function<N extends Number> {
    N calculate(N n1, N n2);
}
```

You can now do something like this:

```
class AddInteger
implements Function<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer calculate(Integer n1, Integer n2) {
        /* actually does
         * return Integer.valueOf(n1.intValue() + n2.intValue()); */
        return n1 + n2;
    }
}
```

You might observe that this is then possible:

```
class AddAlmostAny<N extends Number>
implements Function<N> {
    @Override
    public N calculate(N n1, N n2) {
        if(n1.getClass() != n2.getClass())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unmatched types");

        if(n1 instanceof Integer)
            return (N)new Integer(n1.intValue() + n2.intValue());
        if(n1 instanceof Double)
            return (N)new Double(n1.doubleValue() + n2.doubleValue());
        if(n1 instanceof BigInteger)
            return (N)((BigInteger)n1).add((BigInteger)n2));
        // etc

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown type");
    }
}
```

But that basically defeats the purpose of generics.

Answer (score -1):

Use unbound wildcards and then cast it.

Look here for more info
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html