# Creating a User Defined Aggregate function in Apache Derby

Tags: java, derby

I need to create a User Defined Aggregate (UDA) function in Derby (specifically, a `Variance` function), but I'm kinda stuck with the proper way to write it.

So far, I have the "template" for the UDA:

```
public class Variance<V extends Comparable<V>> implements Aggregator<V,V,Variance<V>> {
    private ArrayList<V> _values;
    public Variance() {/*Empty constructor*/}
    public void init() {_values = new ArrayList<V>(); }
    public void accumulate(V v) { _values.add(v); }
    public void merge(Variance<V> o) { _values.addAll(o._values); }
    public V terminate() {
        // Here is my issue!!!
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is this: To compute the variance I need to calculate something like this:

```
V sum, sumSq;
int n = _values.size();
if(n <= 0)
    return null;
// Initialize sum and sumSq to "zero"
for(V v : _values) {
    sum += v; // Or somehow add v to sum
    sumSq += Math.pow(v, 2); // Or somehow add (v^2) to sumSq
}
return (sumSq - n * Math.pow(sum / n, 2)) / n;
```

... but I don't know how to tell that this is only valid for numeric types (integer, decimal or floating-point values).

I think I'm missing something in my code, but I don't know if there's a way to tell this program that `V` is numeric, and thus, I can use arithmetic operations on values of type `V`.

So, the specific questions are:

- Is there a way to perform this operations (addition, substraction, product, power) on the values?
- Should I change the definition of `V` (somewhat making it extend a "numeric" class, like `Double`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Derby's data types:

```
DECIMAL = java.math.BigDecimal
INTEGER = java.lang.Integer
FLOAT = java.lang.Float or java.lang.Double
```

FLOAT will convert to different Java objects depending on the precision you specify when you create it, the default being java.lang.Double

**Adding numbers**

The first problem you have is simply summing values together (lots of *bad operand types for binary operator '+'* errors).  Also even if you could get Integer, Float and Double to work you would find that because BigDecimal does not map directly to a Java primitive it does not work with the standard primitive arithmetic operators and because of this has it's own add method on the object.

To quote, [Mark Peters answer to a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850970/java-generic-methods-and-numbers);

> There are ways you can hack this together but in all honestly,
>   generics is simply not the way to go here. Build a method for each
>   concrete primitive wrapper type and implement them separately. It'll
>   be way too much of a headache to make it generic; arithmetic
>   operations can't happen generically.

**Squaring values**

The second problem you have is that you are using the power method.

Math.pow() works with double arguments - so Integer or Double calculations should be okay.  Float may display unexpected results as converting a float to a double can result in strange extra digits in the converted value.

The result type for Math.pow is a Double, which you could workaround by defining your Aggregator so that the terminate method result type is always a Double, e.g.:

```
public class Variance<V extends Number & Comparable<V>> 
    implements Aggregator<V, Double, Variance<V>> {
```

As we have seen before BigDecimal is a little different to the others and has its own pow()  method whose result type is a BigDecimal value.

**Conclusion**

Given the above I would suggest that don't attempt a generic solution but instead implement multiple variance aggregators for each class type that you want to support. e.g. your could implement something like:

```
Aggregator<Integer, Double, Variance<Integer>>
Aggregator<Double, Double, Variance<Double>>
Aggregator<Float, Double, Variance<Float>>
Aggregator<BigDecimal, BigDecimal, Variance<BigDecimal>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//that is not the best answer, but works 
            import org.apache.derby.agg.Aggregator; 
            import java.util.ArrayList;

            public class Variance<V extends Double> implements Aggregator<V,V,Variance<V>> {
              private ArrayList<V> list =null; 

               public Variance() {}

               public void init() {
                 list= new ArrayList<>(); 
               }

               public void accumulate(V value) {
                 list.add(value); 
               }

               public void merge(Variance<V> another) {
                 list.addAll(another.list); 
               }

               public V terminate() {
                 double sum=0, sumSq=0;
            int n = list.size();
            if(n <= 0)
                return null;
            // Initialize sum and sumSq to "zero"
            for(Double v : list) {
                sum += v; // Or somehow add v to sum
                sumSq += Math.pow(v, 2); // Or somehow add (v^2) to sumSq
            }
            return (V)(new Double((sumSq - n * Math.pow(sum / n, 2)) / n) ) ;
               }



                public static void main(String [] args) {
                  Variance<Double> v= new Variance<>(); 
                    v.init(); 
                    v.accumulate(new Double(8.0)); 
                     v.accumulate(new Double(6.0)); 
                     v.accumulate(new Double(10.0)); 

                     System.out.println(v.terminate()); 
                }
            }
```

Comment: Some explanation would be great!